# Finding the place of the array

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Im using this function to find which place in the array the title has, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in a better/faster way.

```
func findId(title:String){
        var id = 0
        for restaurant in restaurantObjects{
            if (restaurant.name == title){

                self.idClicked = id
            }
            else{
                id++
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: you could add a break statement after finding the id

Comment: That's a good point! @Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns an optional `Int`, it's `nil` if the index could not be found.

```
func findId(title:String) -> Int? {
  return restaurantObjects.indexOf{ $0.name == title}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Restaurant {
    let name : String
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let restaurantObjects : [Restaurant] = [Restaurant("foo"), Restaurant("foofoo"), Restaurant("bar"), Restaurant("foo")]
let title = "bar"
if let pos = restaurantObjects.indexOf({ $0.name == title }) {
    print("Found \(title) at index \(pos)") // Found bar at index 2
}
```

---

Alternatively, make an array extension for elements of type `Restaurant`, allowing you to simply call `.findFirstId(title: String)` on you array of `Restaurant` objects.

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name : String
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

protocol RestaurantObject {
    var name : String { get }
}
extension Restaurant : RestaurantObject {}

extension Array where Element : RestaurantObject {
    func findFirstId(title: String) -> Int? {
        return self.indexOf { $0.name == title }
    }
}

/* Example */
let restaurantObjects : [Restaurant] = [Restaurant("foo"), Restaurant("foofoo"), Restaurant("bar"), Restaurant("foo")]
let title = "bar"

restaurantObjects.findFirstId(title) // 2
```